# Drupal6: $THEME_URL how to change themes based on full domain path

Tags: drupal

I have this function in my settings.php:

```
$THEME_URLS = array(
array('/optoelectronics','optotemp'),
array('/power-devices','optotemp'),
);
foreach ( $THEME_URLS as $info)
        if ( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],$info[0])===0)
                $conf['theme_default'] = $info[1];
```

..but, I've now realized that all the pre-processing and drupal output happens before hitting the settings.php so in this case above, another site I have sharing content but on a different domain get's the above 'optotemp' theme applied since it also has a /optoelectronics section/page.

I tried using www.sitea.com/optoelectronics but it doesn't seem to work.

I need drupal to recognize the absolute path, the actual domain and not just the /optoelectronics part.

So, I have a custom page with the path url /optoelectronics and two variants. Which variant is served up has selection rules based on domains. Works perfectly. Now, since siteA has a new theme but needs to keep the old theme for the /optoelectronics section I thought the above function would work but I discovered it serves up that theme no matter what the actual domain is.

How can I serve up a different theme based on the actual domain? D6

NOTE: I am using the Domain Access module to serve up content based on the domain. But, I need to control the theme for two sections of one site, while leaving those sections as-is on the second site.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this issue: http://drupal.org/node/622450

See the two modules mentioned on the top but also the hook_init() function in
http://drupal.org/node/622450#comment-2224478

Comment: Hmm... if I understood that, those seem to be based on an IP or a range. The issue w/our site is that all of our domains point to our one main site, www.mainsite.com lets say, and then via the Domain Access and selection rules on pages, the appropriate content is served up for the domain. So the IP is the same. That's one of my issues.... I need to check the full domain/path because multiple sites have the same relative url and all have the same IP, techinically.